# Proving that the limit of an abstract function with certain properties is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $$F(x) = \sum_{a \leq x} f(a)$$ where $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that:

1. $f(a) \geq 0$ for any $a \in A$ and
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{a \in A} f(a) = 1$

How do I prove that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} F(x) = 0\text{?}$$ I know how to do delta-epsilon proofs for limits that take $x$ to infinity, but I don't know any theorems that let me exploit the two conditions on the function allowing me to prove the following limit without having to "peak inside" the function to see what it looks like. My real analysis is very rusty.

Comment: What is the set $A$?

Comment: I don't understand. How can we have $f(a)=0$ for every $a\in A$ but also have $\sum_{a\in A}f(a)=1$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Perhaps, but then wouldn't $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 1$? In fact, shouldn't we have $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = \sum_{a\in A}f(a)$?

Comment: You're both wrong. I meant to write $f(a) \geq 0$.

Comment: I suspect that OP was supposed to prove that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x) = 1$.

Comment: @Dr. Bales thank you for your suspicion, but I am trying to prove a particular property of any cumulative distribution function (whether continuous or discrete) and the property I am trying to prove is that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$.

Comment: It is not necessary to mention the concept of countability in order to prove the desired result. See my answer below. I believe in trying to make things appear as simple as the actually are.

Comment: @uniquesolution. $A$ is just some anonymous subset of  $\mathbb R.$ The subscript on the summation  symbol in the def'n of $F(x)$ should really be "'$\;a\leq x\land a\in A\;$"..... BTW in  case $A=\phi$ it is customary to define the sum of the members of the empty set to be $0.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following fact below, so I thought it would be useful to prove it first.

> If $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(a)\geq 0$ for every $a\in A$ and $\sum_{a\in A}f(a)<\infty$, then $[f>0]$ (notation for $\{a\in A \mid f(a)>0\}$) is countable.

*Proof:*
For each $x>0$, consider the set $[f>x]$. Note that
$$
\operatorname{card}([f>x])x \leq \sum_{a\in[f>x]}f(a) \leq \sum_{a\in A}f(a) < \infty.
$$
Thus $[f>x]$ is finite. Therefore $[f>0] = \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[f>1/n]$ is countable, as it is a countable union of finite sets. $\square$

Now we consider the problem. Since $f(a)\geq0$ for all $a\in A$ and $\sum_{a\in A}f(a)$ converges, it must converge absolutely. Let $A':=\{a\in A \mid f(a)>0\}$. Then $A'$ must be countable, for otherwise $\sum_{a\in A}f(a)$ would diverge. Let's enumerate $A'=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ [thanks to Adayah for noticing mistake here]. Now we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(a_n) = \sum_{a\in A'}f(a)=\sum_{a\in A}f(a)= 1.
$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since the above sum converges, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(a_n) < \varepsilon$.
Then whenever $x<\min_{n< N}a_n$, we have
$$
F(x) = \sum_{a\leq x}f(a) \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty f(a_n) < \varepsilon.
$$
This proves that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$. $\square$

I want to remark that we didn't actually need $\sum_{a\in A}f(a)=1$. We just needed the sum to converge.

---

Response to old version of question:

Even with the edits, there still seems to be something wrong. Consider $A=\{0\}$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(0) = 1$. Then indeed $f(a)\geq 0$ for any $a\in A$ and $\sum_{a\in A}f(a)=1$. However, for all $x\geq 0$, we have $F(x)=1$. Therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$.

Comment: Whoops. Good catch. It was supposed to be $\lim_{x \to -\infty}$. I forgot a minus sign.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich Ah that makes much more sense! See edit.

Comment: I posted an answer assuming $x\to+\infty$ and showed the limit is $1.$ I think a similar argument to show the limit as $x\to-\infty$ is $0,$ and in fact I think it will be simpler than this one in that it need not mention the concept of countability. I believe in trying to make things as simple as they really are.

Comment: This is a very good answer!

Comment: Very clear. I noticed that if we assume there exists $r\in \mathbb R$ such that $F(x)\in \mathbb R$ for all $x\leq r$ (that is $F(x)\ne \infty$ for all $x\leq r$) then Condition 2 ($\sum_{a\in A}f(a)=1$) is unnecessary, and that your answer could easily be  modified to handle this different version,,,,, BTW, in the Q, the subscript on the summation symbol in the def'n of $F(x)$ should be "$\;x\geq a\in A\;$", which may be obvious to some.

Comment: You have a minor mistake: it's not always possible to enumerate $A' = \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots \}$ in a decreasing way. Take $A' = \mathbb{Q}$ for example. To correct it, we can replace $x \leqslant a_{N+1}$ with $\displaystyle x < \min_{n \leqslant N} a_n$ and then $\displaystyle \sum_{a \leqslant x} f(a) \leqslant \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} f(a_n)$.

Comment: @Adayah Wow thank you!

Answer (score 6):

What does it mean to say
$$
\sum_{a\,\in\,A} f(a) = 1 \text{ ?}
$$
Since every term of this sum is non-negative, we can defined it like this:
$$
\sum_{a\,\in\,A} f(a) = \sup \left\{ \sum_{a\,\in\,A_0} f(a) : A_0 \text{ is a finite subset of } A \right\}.
$$
Thus we have $\forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists A_0\subseteq A\ \Big( A_0 \text{ is finite and } \sum\limits_{a\,\in\,A_0} f(a) > 1 - \varepsilon\Big).$

Since $A_0$ is finite, it has a largest member. Then whenever $x\ge\max A_0,$ we have
$$
\sum_{a\,\le\,x} f(a) \ge \sum_{a\,\in\,A_0} f(a) > 1-\varepsilon.
$$
So
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\  \exists X\in\mathbb R\  \forall x\ge X\ \sum_{a\,\le\,x} f(a) > 1- \varepsilon.
$$
That means
$$
\lim_{x\,\to\,\infty} \sum_{a\,\le\, x} f(a) = 1.
$$
**Important corollary:** By the same argument, we have
$$
\lim_{x\,\to\,-\infty} \sum_{a\,>\,x} f(a) = 1,
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\,\to\,-\infty} \sum_{a\,\le\,x} f(a) = \lim_{x\,\to\,-\infty} \left( 1 - \sum_{a\,\le\,x} f(a) \right) = 1 - 1 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_0=A\cap(0,+\infty)$, $a_0=\sum\limits_{a\in A_0}f(a)$, and also
$$A_n=A\cap(-n,-n+1], \quad a_n=\sum_{a\in A_n}f(a), \quad \text{for }n=1,2,3\ldots.$$

Then the two given conditions imply that:

1. $F(x)$ is a monotonically non-decreasing function;
2. each $a_n$ satisfies $0\le a_n\le1$ for all $n=0,1,2,3\ldots$;
3. $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=\sum\limits_{a\in A}f(a)=1$;
4. $F(-n)=\sum\limits_{a\le-n}f(a)=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_k$ for all $n=1,2,3\ldots$.

Then the sequence $F(-1),F(-2),F(-3),\ldots,F(-n),\ldots$ is the sequence of remainders of a convergent series, and therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to-\infty}F(n)=0$. Together with the non-decreasing behavior, it implies that $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Response to the original version:

If $A$ is the set of natural numbers and $f(a)=\dfrac{1}{2^a}$ then the desired limit is not $0$.

Comment: The limit is towards $-\infty$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh  Yes, I see that the OP has changed the limit from $x\to\infty$ to $x\to-\infty$. Thanks for pointing out the change.